# Using winhttp.h many unknown type specifiers

Tags: c++, types

I wanted to write something using the winhttp library, but when include the header in my project in Visual Studio and compile it, it throws a lot of errors, that it does not recognize type specifiers like :  LPVOID, HINTERNET, WORD, DWORD,, LPWSTR and more.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `#include <windows.h>` first.